# LINQ - Displaying User's Friends' book list

Tags: c#, linq

I’m working on a project that has the following model:

[image]

I am successfully able to create a user with friends, create a user with books, and create friends with books.

What I am trying to do now, is display a User’s friends’ book list.

In my database, I have two Users:

1 Jill

2 Jack

Jill and Jack are both Friends.

If logged in as Jill, I can successfully display Jack’s Books with this query:

```
List<int> friendsIds = db
          .Friends
          .Where(c => c.User.Id == u.Id || c.User1.Id == u.Id)
          .Select(c => c.User1.Id)
          .ToList<int>();

List<Book> friendsBooks = db
                         .Books
                         .Where(c => friendsIds.Contains((int)c.UserId))
                         .ToList<Book>();
labelMyBooks.Text = sBooks;

string sMyFriendsBooks = "";
foreach (Book b in friendsBooks)
{
    sMyFriendsBooks += b.BookTitle + ",";
}
labelMyFriendsBooks.Text = sMyFriendsBooks;
```

I assumed that, if logged in as Jack, the same query would provide Jill’s Books. But it provides Jack’s Book List instead.

I want to log in as Jack and display Jill’s Book List. What am I missing here? Does it have to do with the order the Users are in in the Database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial `.Select(...)` method is the cause - it always selects `c.User1.Id` when it should select `c.User.Id` when the match is on `c.User1.Id`

Try the following:

```
var f1 = db.Friends.Where(c => c.User.Id == u.Id).Select(c => c.User1.Id);
var f2 = db.Friends.Where(c => c.User1.Id == u.Id).Select(c => c.User.Id);

List<int> friendIds = f1.Union(f2).ToList();
```

Now, your entities are defined in a confusing manner.  `Friend` isn't really a friend entity, it's a relationship between two `User` entities.  `Friendship` would describe it more accurately.  The nav properties in `User` could be better described as `FriendOf` and `FriendsWith` to define *ownership* of the friendship (i.e. Id vs User1.Id in the friendship table).  This should make things clearer:

```
var friends = u.FriendsWith.Union( u.FriendOf );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when selecting the friend list. The right query should be like this:

```
 List<int> friendsIds = db.Friends.Where(c => c.User.Id == u.Id || c.User1.Id == u.Id)
.Select(c => c.User1.Id==u.Id?c.User.Id: c.User1.Id).ToList<int>();
```

Because you should select c.User.Id in case c.User1.Id is the u.Id and the c.User.Id otherwise.